# Java Filter with error dispatcher explanation

Tags: java, filter, error-handling

Can someone explain what `<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>` means? I cannot find any examples about it. I wanted to handle bad requests (for example when someone makes typo) with Filter and from it to forward to some jsp file. I wrote the following code:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>badRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filter.BadRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>badRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I know that I can use `<error-page>` in `web.xml`, but I decide to try this(for practice). But this filter is not called and typos are not catched. What can be the reason for that? Maybe I misunderstood when this types of filters are called. 
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324114/what-is-an-error-dispatch-in-servlet-processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>` sets that the filter is only applied to requests [dispatched](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getDispatcherType--) to an error page.

But if you don't specify a error page in web.xml this filter is not invoked.
(At least that is the behaviour in Tomcat).