# Disable default error response body in Jetty 9.4.2

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jetty, servlet-3.0

How can I disable the default response body when Jetty catches an exception and returns an error? I am not using any XML or WAR and I don't want to add any.

I prefer to avoid doing a `try { // Servlet code } catch (Exception e) { resp.setStatus(500) }` in every servlet.

If I don't do that, Jetty will return a 500 response with a body that specifies the stack trace. If a not found endpoint is reached, Jetty will return a 404 response with a body that says "Powered by Jetty". I want to remove those bodies and just keep the response code.

This is the code that starts my Jetty server:

```
private static void startServer() throws Exception {
    final org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(7070);
    final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext("/", "/");
    context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] { new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebInfConfiguration() });
    context.setExtraClasspath("build/classes/main/com/example");
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is described in the [Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/custom-error-pages.html#_custom_errorhandler_class):

A class extending `ErrorHandler` is needed in order to override Jetty default behavior when generating the error page. It may be registered via the `ContextHandler` or the Jetty server.

The `CustomErrorHandler` class:

```
public class CustomErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    protected void writeErrorPage(HttpServletRequest request, Writer writer, int code, String message, boolean showStacks) throws IOException {}
}
```

I then added this to my Jetty embedded configuration:
`context.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());`

Comment: If you are adding this to a WebAppContext, you need to extend from `ErrorPageErrorHandler`, not `ErrorHandler` (as that's for non-context, and Server side errors)

Answer (score 1):

In your `WEB-INF/web.xml` of your war file, specify the `<error-page>` element you want to use to handle the errors.

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myerror</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.MyErrorServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myerror</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myerror</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <error-page>
    <location>/myerror</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

The `<error-page>` element can be quite powerful.

See other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16340504/775715

Comment: I'm not using any XML or WAR artifact, just annotations for servlets. Is there a programatic solution? In your solution, will every error (500, 404, etc) go to the same MyErrorServlet? I want to return the same error code but without the Jetty response body that leaks data.

Comment: The fact that you are using a `WebAppContext` means you are using a war (it can be an exploded directory).  You cannot specify error-page with annotations (there's no annotation for it), you must use the `WEB-INF/web.xml`.  See the other answer to understand error dispatch and the attributes about the error state.