# Logging API request and response using DispatcherServlet in SpringBoot - dispatcher executed twice

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I've created a custom `DispatcherServlet` implementation in Spring Boot 3.2.0, that's aimed for logging incoming API calls. The goal is to log all incoming (request) and outcoming (response) data, including payloads (body). The following implementation works fine for successful calls, but for some reason, it gets executed twice if controller throws an exception, resulting two entries in the log, which is not expected behaviour.

Here is implementation of the `DispatcherServlet`.

```
public class LoggerDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
    
    @Override
    protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wReq;
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wResp;

        if(request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper) {
            wReq = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper)request;
        } else {
            wReq = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        }

        if (response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper) {
            wResp = (ContentCachingResponseWrapper)response;
        } else {
            wResp = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        }

        try {
            super.doDispatch(wReq, wResp);
        } finally {
            log(wReq, wResp);
            wResp.copyBodyToResponse();
        }

    }

    private void log(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request, ContentCachingResponseWrapper response) {
        //omitted
        System.out.println("Logging...");
    }
}
```

Here is the bean registration:

```
@Bean(name = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    return new LoggerDispatcherServlet();
}
```

Test endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/api/test/error")
public void unauthorized(@RequestBody() Map<String, ?> body) {
    throw new ResponseStatusException(
        HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
        "ERROR"
    );
}
```

Output after call:

```
Logging...
Logging...
```

In this scenario, when the first execution happens, there is no response body. In the second execution, there is no request body and different URL when calling `request.getRequestURI()`.

Log entry from calling the endpoint (real scenario):

```
[Request]
Timestamp: 26.11.2023 23:24:07.346
Url: /api/test/error
Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 13
Payload: {"test": 123}

[Response]
Timestamp: 26.11.2023 23:24:07.420
Status: 401
Content-Type: null
Content-Length: 0
Payload: null

[Request]
Timestamp: 26.11.2023 23:24:07.431
Url: /error
Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Payload: null

[Response]
Timestamp: 26.11.2023 23:24:07.475
Status: 401
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 106
Payload: {"timestamp":"2023-11-26T22:36:28.081+00:00","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"ERROR","path":"/api/test/error"}
```

Is there a way to prevent it from executing twice? Or any workaround to properly log first request and second response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you don't provide your own error handling. Because of that, you rely on Spring's error handling which relies on [error dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16324114/1915448) and forwards the request internally to the [`BasicErrorController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/BasicErrorController.html) at `/error`.

This information can also be found in [this blogpost](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#fallback-error-page):

> 1. In the event of any unhanded error, Spring Boot forwards internally to `/error`.
> 2. Boot sets up a `BasicErrorController` to handle any request to `/error`. The controller adds error information to the internal Model and returns error as the logical view name.

So if you want to see the request and response in a single servlet-call, the easiest way would be to add your own error handling.

For example:

```java
@PostMapping("/api/test/error")
public void unauthorized(@RequestBody() Map<String, ?> body) {
    throw new CustomUnauthorizedException();
}

@ExceptionHandler(CustomUnauthorizedException.class)
public ProblemDetail handleCustomUnauthorizedException(CustomUnauthorizedException ex) {
    return ProblemDetail.forStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, ex.getMessage());
}
```

You can register this exception handler within a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to do similar approach, but I cannot change the structure of the error response client gets. This does change the structure of error response. The standard ErrorController properly sets status codes for specific exceptions (500 for unexpected exceptions, status code for ResponseStatusException, 401 for UnauthorizedException and so on). Isn't there more generic approach? Like use the logic of generating response like the ErrorController does. Client must see what he has seen before logging.

Comment: @t4dohx You probably can by checking the implementation of `BasicErrorController`. The problem is that as far as I can tell, it uses the error request attributes which are passed down to the `/error` request. So since you don't want to use `/error`, you'd have to replicate that as well.

Comment: Alright, I'll figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: EDIT: So technically, creating an ExceptionHandler for Throwable, will result that logging with OncePerRequestFilter will work as well. Is using a filter rather than dispatcher a better approach?

Comment: @t4dohx Creating an `@ExceptionHandler` for `Throwable` is indeed an option, though personally I think I would prefer handling each exception separately. Using a `Filter` is indeed the prefered way to go.

Comment: You may also want to check out [Logbook](https://github.com/zalando/logbook), which pretty much does what you want to do. But be aware that in Logbook it's also recommended to write your own exception handlers for the same reason as you can see [here](https://github.com/zalando/logbook/issues/488#issuecomment-486227665).

Answer (score 0):

In Short, if you just want to log requests, try implementing a OncePerRequestFilter. don't try to crack the abstraction.

Comment: I want to log both requests and responses, including payloads. It's not possible to log error responses with filters, or is?

Comment: you can do it with filters. If you have any questions, please refer to the logical architecture diagram of the Servlet API. I believe that will resolve many of your doubts."

Comment: There won't be spring-generated-error response body if the controller throws an exeption, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Using a filter won't help you here. The issue is that when you throw an unhandled exception, Spring internally forwards it to `/error`, where an `ErrorController` will pick it up. For both the `DispatcherServlet` and a `Filter`, these count as two separate calls. Using a `OncePerRequestFilter` would make it worse, because as @t4dohx mentioned, it won't log what the `ErrorController` does because the request attributes remain the same across the original request and the originally forwarded one (and these attributes are used to determine whether a request is already processed).

Comment: @g00glen00b - that makes sense. Is there a way to determine, if the `super.doDispatch()` threw an exception? I cannot rely on http status, since using `return ResponseEntity.status(401)` does not have said behaviour. I've managed to omit logging of second request by storing a `boolean` in `ThreadLocal` after the log method has been called, meaning that if the value is present, the Dispatcher is called for the second time. However, this is just a temporary workaroud.